# Can the column value of a SharePoint list be validated against another data source (e.g. CSV)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, validation

I am looking to build a SharePoint list and need various columns to only allow values from another data source. The data source to validate against will be extracted from another database as CSV.

For example, I have a field of unique references extracted from the other data source. I would like the corresponding SharePoint list column to only allow values from this unique references list.

Can anyone advise on possible solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How do you import data in the csv file to the SharePoint list columns?

Whether you create a new list through "From Excel", PowerShell or through flow?

Per my knowledge and test, there is no OOTB option to limit values in SharePoint list columns from only one csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a remote event receiver. You'll need to create one on Item being added and validate the value and stop execution if it doesn't match what you need. More details and steps are available here: https://www.tatvasoft.com.au/blog/how-to-implement-remote-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-online/

Answer (score 0):

We've just done something identical.  We first imported the csv to a Sharepoint list, on our sharepoint site, and then we created a document library, with one of the columns set to be a Lookup column which references the list you've created to receive the csv data.

It's all fairly straightforward really.